# FB API PHP SDK - session lost when refreshing page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

At first let's take a look at two files:

- `index.php`

  ```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf=8" />
    <title>FB App</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <?php
    define( 'FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'src/Facebook/');
    require __DIR__ . '\autoload.php';

    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/app/back.php','APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET' );
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
    ?>

  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- `back.php`

  ```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
  <?php
  define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', 'src/Facebook/');
  require __DIR__ . '\autoload.php';

  use Facebook\FacebookSession;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
  use Facebook\GraphUser;
  use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
  use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

  FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET' );
  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://localhost/app/back.php' );
  try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
      // When Facebook returns an error
  } catch(\Exception $ex) {
     // When validation fails or other local issues
  }
  if ( $session ) {
      // Logged in.
      echo 'logged in';
      echo '<hr/>';
      // set session from cookie or via helper
      $user_id = $session->getSessionInfo()->asArray()['user_id'];
      $request = new FacebookRequest(
          $session,
          'GET',
          '/' . $user_id
      );
      $response = $request->execute();
      $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
      echo 'you are ' . $graphObject->getProperty( 'name' );
  }
  ?>
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf=8" />
    <title>FB App BACK</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Loging in proceeds successfully and I can see I'm logged in. Yet, when the page is reloaded I get `Undefined variable: session in C:\wamp\www\app\back.php on line 21`, it is line

```
if ( $session ) {
```

How to keep a session in the website consisting of multiple pages?

Comment: Put `$session` into the session …?

Comment: `session_start()` put before including SDK was problem, it works as you wrote and I meant ;)